# What is a weight of space?

Tags: general-topology, definition

I came across a paper (sourced below), where the author was talking about a weight of a topological space. In particular, they said the space is "of a countable weight". What does this mean in your opinion? I haven´t found any definition or other reference to weight in the article.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

The paper: [Topological compactifications](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266999999_Topological_compactifications)

Comment: The [weight](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Weight_of_a_topological_space) of a topological space is the smallest cardinality of an open base.  In particular, countable weight = second countable.

Comment: Okay, so countable weight basically means countable basis. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close the question: weight is just one of the many so-called *cardinal invariants* of a topological space.

Given a space $X$ we can consider the set of all bases for the topology of $X$ and this itself forms a set and so it has a member of minimal cardinality (as cardinal numbers are well-ordered) and this minimal size of a base for $X$ is called the *weight* of $X$, or $w(X)$. By common convention we round it up to $\aleph_0$ (or countable) in the case where this is a finite number (which happens for finite spaces and some trivial topologies on infinite sets $X$).

So saying the weight of $X$ is countable is just a fancy way of saying that $X$ has at least one countable (or finite) base for its topology, which is also called "$X$ is second countable" or $X$ is $C$-II in some texts.

Another common cardinal invariant is the density of $X$, $d(X)$, which is the size of a minimal dense set, so $d(X)$ countable means that $X$ is separable, etc. See this [encyclopaedia article](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic) for more examples.

Defining these cardinal numbers allows us to succinctly state facts like $|X|\le 2^{\chi(X)l(X)}$, which is a classical theorem due to Arkhangel'skij. Many papers use these invariants as handy shortcuts.